# Evaluating a cube root

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

How to evaluate  $(8.024)^{1/3}$ from $(1+3x)^{1/3}$.I already expand it until $x^3$ but i still can't get the answer. I tried googling for the working using binomial theorem but i failed.

Comment: $8.024 = 8\cdot 1.003 = 2^3\cdot (1 + 3\cdot 0.001)$

Answer (score 2):

Using Daniel's comment:
$(8.024)^{1/3} = 2*(1+3\cdot0.001)^{1/3}$ 
so
$x=0.001$
Taylor sequence:
$(1+3x)^{1/3} = 1+x-x^2+\frac{5}{3}x^3$

Substituting $x=0.001$:

$(8.024)^{1/3} = 2*(1+3\cdot0.001)^{1/3} = 2(1+0.001-10^{-6}+\frac{5}{3}10^{-9}) = 2(1.0009990017) = 2.001998$